# Android Imageview not updated on camera result activity

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

An imageview is not being updated with a photo taken in a camera activity on my Samsung 4S phone app.  I save the Uri of the photo in a saveinstancestate and the photo is there on the camera but it does not update the imageview.  Below is the code.

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap image1;
        if(requestCode == RESULT_CROP_IMAGE)
        {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            image1 = extras.getParcelable("data");
        }
        else {
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE) {
                selectedImage = imageUri;  // this gets the photo just taken
            } else
                selectedImage = data.getData();  // this gets an existing photo and it works
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            image1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        }
        displayphoto = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image1, newWidth, newHeight, true);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
        imageView.setEnabled(true);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(displayphoto);
        Button cropPhoto = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cropPhoto);
        cropPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Not only is the imageView not showing the image, the cropPhoto button does not appear either.  In debug mode I can see that the instructions are being executed and I examined the dimensions of the returned photo which are correct but nothing shows up.  However, if I get an existing photo from my camera, everything works so I know it has something to do with losing global variables.  I know that the instancestate has to be retrieved for certain objects when taking a photo and I do that in the code below so I know my imageUri is returned properly.

```
      @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putParcelable("myURI", imageUri);
    savedInstanceState.putString("myPath", mCurrentPhotoPath);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    imageUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("myURI");
    mCurrentPhotoPath = savedInstanceState.getString("myPath");
   }
```

So what is missing here?  Why does not my image or my button show up?  Does it have something to do with losing global variables when taking a photo?  Also, I should mention that every once in awhile it works and the image appears.  I don't understand why it normally doesn't appear.

Comment: Have you tried setting image1 in imageView. First check that and then scale your bitmap

Comment: That didn't work either.  The image only works randomly which makes me believe there is something missing in the environment.  I can't believe something this simple should be so hard.  Very frustrating.  My camera app in IOS works perfectly.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. But on my case, it was that my imageview is on a recyclerview item, onActivityResult doesn't guarantee that those views where inflated. Technically, nothing happens.